# PHP 7 in Windows: DOMDocument not found

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have seen the various answers about [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) not found for Linux systems, but I cannot find the corresponding information for Windows based PHP systems. The documentation seems to imply this is built into Windows PHP but I am getting a 'DOMDocument not found' error whilst running Laravel.

How do I use the DOMDocument class in Windows PHP?

**Update: Solved** just needed:

```
use \DOMDocument;
```

Comment: It is certainly present in PHP 7.3.rc6. A simple `$xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-15" );` worked just fine.

Comment: Can you show your code? Domdocument should be available out of the box.

Comment: I've solved it by `use \DOMDocument;`